# List files in azure file storage and get the most recent file

Tags: python-3.x, azure, file-storage

I have files in azure file storage, so I listed the files by the date upload and then I want to select the most recent file uploaded.
So to do this, I created a function that should have returned me, the list of the files. However when I see the output, it return only one file and the other are missing.

Here is my code:

```
file_service = FileService(account_name='', account_key='')
generator = list(file_service.list_directories_and_files(''))

    def list_files_in(generator,file_service):
        list_files=[]
        for file_or_dir in generator:
            file_in = file_service.get_file_properties(share_name='', directory_name="", file_name=file_or_dir.name)
            file_date= file_in.properties.last_modified.date()
            list_tuple = (file_date,file_or_dir.name)
            list_files.append(list_tuple)
            return list_files
```

Comment: When get the list of the files get it sorted based on "CREATION TIME" metadata of the files.

Comment: can you explain better please?

Comment: i have added the ans in detail you can follow along ,use last_modified or creation_time which ever is correct in your scenario

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest files in azure blob you need to write the logic to get that, below are the code which will give you the same :

**For Files**

```
result = file_service.list_directories_and_files(share_name, directory_name)
for file_or_dir in result:
    if isinstance(file_or_dir, File):
    file = file_service.get_file_properties(share_name, directory_name, file_name, timeout=None, snapshot=None)
    print(file_or_dir.name, file.properties.last_modified)
```

**For Blob**

```
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient

container = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(conn_str={your_connection_string}, container_name = {your_container_name})
for blob in container.list_blobs():
    print(f'{blob.name} : {blob.last_modified}')
```

You can get the key's and account details from the azure portal for the account access. In this `blob.last_modified` will give you latest blob item.

Comment: Hi @Rahul, thanks for the help, but this didn't changed the output that I wanted. I altered my question to a more specific doubt. Please take a look if you can. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Rahul did you take a look at the new edit of this post? Thank you for your help